# Adding SelectListItem to SelectList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MVC app using the Entity framework. I have two entities, user and faculty.

I'm trying to add the faculties to a select list for a dropdown box used during the editing of a user. I'm getting the error:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'"

I googled around and been through a few solutions to similar questions on here but had no luck.

**EditUserModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Purely_Servers.Models
{
    public class EditUserModel
    {
        public user User { get; set; }
        public SelectList FacultyList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**usersController**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }


        var model = new EditUserModel
        {
            User = db.Users.Find(id),
            FacultyList = (
                from f in db.Faculties
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = f.id.ToString(),
                    Text = f.name
                }).ToList() /////////////////////ERROR HERE
        };


        if (model == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: your problem is that the result is of type List while your property is of type SelectList, try to make it like FacultyList= new SelectList((..query..).ToList());

Comment: As others have stated, the easiest solution to this would be to change the type of your FacultyList from SelectList to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ToList()`, the enumerable is converted to a `List<SelectListItem>`, which cannot be cast to a `SelectList`.

You have 2 options:

1. Change the `FacultyList` property to be of type `List<SelectListItem>`.
2. Convert the query to a `SelectList` (see code below).

Code for option 2:

```
FacultyList = new SelectList(
    from f in db.Faculties
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = f.id.ToString(),
        Text = f.name
    });
```

Comment: Or just `FacultyList = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "id", "name");`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FacultyList { get; set; }
```

and:

```
 FacultyList = (
                from f in db.Faculties
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = f.id.ToString(),
                    Text = f.name
                });
```

Comment: It's always best to use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. The helpers like `Html.DropDownListFor` take this naturally, and handle creating the select list / selecting the appropriate item in the list automatically.

Comment: When using this solution I get syntax errors on the last line of the above code. It's expecting a , and { .....any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help to someone.

```
        CostCenterHeaders CostHeaders = CostCenterHeaders.GetCostCenterHeaders(ClientNumber);
        List<SelectListItem> Level1Header = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (CostHeaders.Level1Heading !=null)
        {
            Level1Header.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All " + CostHeaders.Level1Heading + " Centers", Value = "" });
            List<HierarchyLevel> HierarchyLevels = HierarchyLevel.GetHierarchyByLevel(ClientNumber);
            Level1Header.AddRange(HierarchyLevels.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.LevelID, Text = x.LevelDescr }).ToList());
        }
```